# How to Handle Nil Errors in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, error-handling, runtime-error, null

What is the correct way to deal with nil errors in Rails? I often get errors like:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `questions' for nil:NilClass):

For example, let's say I have chapters in my app which each have a question. I would like to call the question from the previous chapter from within the current question, so I write the following code in question.rb:

```
def previous_question
 self.chapter.previous.question
end
```

This might cause the above-mentioned error, so I write a method in the model to check if this will lead to a nil result:

```
def has_previous_question?
 self.chapter and self.chapter.previous and self.chapter.previous.question
end
```

If I make sure to call that before calling `previous_question`, it can work, but it looks ridiculous. Is there a better way to deal with nil errors in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not tell this is THE right way but it is another way of handling this kind of situation:

```
def previous_question
  self.chapter.previous.try(:question)
end
```

That way there won't be any error, if there is no previous chapter, the method will simply return **nil**.

If you want to return something else in case it is actually nil, you can write:

```
def previous_question
  self.chapter.previous.try(:question) || returning_this_value_instead
end
```

Side note: you don't need to use self in that kind of situation:

```
def previous_question
  chapter.previous.try(:question) || returning_this_value_instead
end
```

Comment: You could also chain the `try`: `self.try(:chapter).try(:previous).try(:question)`

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite view rendering methods:

http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach is using [nil objects](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/20907555103/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object), although they are not suitable for every situation...